# Filter or Log MySQL log for a particular table

Tags: mysql, mysql-slow-query-log

In MySQL via are getting the logs from the file `/var/log/mysql/mysql.log` and we can monitoring the live queries through tailing this file using the `tail` command.

The problem is all the queries are logging here, Is there any way to log or filter from tail when the query from a particular table is fired

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [pt-query-digest](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-query-digest.html).

Making a filter based on a table name is tricky, and depends on some undocumented features.

```
pt-query-digest --filter '$qr->distill($event->{arg}) =~ /\bMyTable\b/' \
 /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
```

Note I'm parsing the slow query log, not the general query log. I prefer to use the slow-query log because it has more information in it.

Also be cautious about running this on your production server. I've seen the script take a lot of resources, and it can interfere with your server's load if your log is too large. I recommend you scp the log to some other host where high load won't interfere with your production app.

Comment: FWIW, I logged a doc request for pt-query-digest to add this use case as an example in the doc. https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-toolkit/+bug/1733934 Feel free (i.e. please do) give this doc request some love by clicking "affects me" to raise its priority.